# Array multidimensional de tipos diferentes

Tags: java, array, lista, array-multidimensional

Tenho uma *view* no banco da minha aplicação onde contabilizo o nome do usuário, o setor dele e o total de registros emitidos(conto de outra tabela):

> Tabela(View) TotalPorUsuario
>
> Colunas: nome(string), setor(String), total(int)

Preciso armazenar essas 3 informações em um *array* e retornar do *model* pra *view* e relacionar em uma `JTable`, mas não estou conseguindo imaginar como criar um `arraylist` multidimensional. Pensei em Map mas não conheço bem seu funcionamento.

O meu código atual está(só consegui fazendo com 2 colunas):

```
 public List getTotal() {

        String query = "select nome,setor,total from TotalPorUsuario";
        List<ArrayList> lista1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            this.con = ConnectionFactory.createConnection();
            this.pstm = this.con.prepareStatement(query);
            this.r = this.pstm.executeQuery();

            while (this.r.next()) {
                l2.add(this.r.getString("nome"));
                l3.add(this.r.getInt("total"));
            }
            lista1.add(l2);
            lista1.add(l3);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExcecaoPadrao(ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, pstm, r);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return lista1;
    }
```

Qual a forma recomendada de retornar as três colunas: em 3 `Arraylist` ou existe uma forma menos complexa usando `map`?

Comment: Diego F , use Object

Comment: @RodrigoSantiago não entendi.

Comment: ArrayList<Object> , pode conter qualquer tipo, e melhor ainda ArrayList<Object[]> pode conter todos os valores recuperados pelo ResultSet. Isso vale até para dados primários, o java já converte pra Integer,Boolean etc.

Comment: Isso eu já estou fazendo, só que tenho que adicionar mais uma coluna, ai seriam 3 arraylists dentro do list. Queria saber se existe uma forma de fazer uma coisas dessas seja com arraylist ou map de forma mais simplificada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agradeço as sugestões dadas, me tiraram a dúvida em relação a qual forma usar. Acabei optando por adicionar um atributo na classe usuário, pois usaria os dados para popular um `JTable` e já tenho um `TableModel` customizado, que pode ser reutilizado para a classe `Usuario`. Essa alteração me pareceu menos custosa que implementar lista dentro de lista ou o o `Tuple`.

```
public class Usuario{

    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private Setor setor;
    private boolean estaAtivo = true;
    private int totalDeRegistros;

    /** ... */

    public int getTotalDeRegistros() {
        return this.totalDeRegistros;
    }

    public void setTotalDeRegistros(int total) {
        this.totalDeRegistros = total;
    }

    /** ... */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Normalmente isto é resolvido criando uma classe para conter essas duas colunas e aí você coloca objetos destas classe na lista. É um *container* dentro de outro, primeiro coloca em uma estrutura de dados simples, depois coloca em outra que é uma lista de elementos.

Como o Java não permite tipos anônimos de forma simples, as alternativas seriam criar classes genéricas (tuplas) que permitam alocas estas "colunas" ou fazer o que está fazendo. Exemplo de tupla com 2 elementos:

```
public class Tuple<X, Y> { 
    public final X x; 
    public final Y y; 
    public Tuple(X x, Y y) { 
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y; 
    } 
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Tuple.java).

Tem [algo pronto](http://www.javatuples.org/).

Acho que a solução de tupla deve ser evitado em uma linguagem como o Java. Isto funciona melhor em linguagens com menos cerimônia.

Existem outras gambiarras que não recomendo e nem vou falar, como a citada em comentário.

Comment: Eu até tenho uma classe usuario e outra setor, e usuario tem setor, mas a coluna total é que gera o problema. Somente nesse método é que vou usa-la. Esse método tuple, por acaso, permite um terceiro elemento genérico, aplicando a sua mesma lógica?

Comment: Permite quantos você quiser, você cria como quiser, no *link* tem vários prontos para algumas quantidades. Mas novamente, criar uma classe própria para isto seria melhor.

Comment: Diego, se você já possui a classe usuário, não seria o caso de fazer um map entre o usuário e o número de setores?

Answer (score 4):

Diego,

como eu vi que você busca do banco de dados por uma view, o que me leva a acreditar que a relação total por usuário é algo muito especial para você. 
Acredito que esse seria o caso de criar uma classe para representar a sua view na aplicação.

Algo como:

```
class TotalPorUsuario{
    private Integer total;
    private Usuario usuario;
    //o resto que você precisa
    ...
}
```

e então simplesmente fazer uma lista de objetos que representam a sua view (TotalPorUsuario).

Comment: Tenho já o model de usuario pronto, mas ter que criar um parametro e ficar fazendo getter e setter pra usar uma unica vez num unico método é trabalho desperdiçado.

Comment: @DiegoF isto é Java :)

Comment: @DiegoF, talvez criar essa classe pareça trabalho desperdiçado, porém isso te ajuda a manter as coisas lógicas e de fácil manutenção, Porque já tive que dar manutenção em código onde tinha que advinhar o que significava isso: `lista[0][1][5]`. E acredite, o seu eu do futuro te agradecerá por não utilizar algo do tipo.

Comment: Rubico Meu "eu" do presente está nesse momento odiando o "eu" do passado por ter inventado essa view hehe... Mas vou ver o quanto eu vou ter que alterar o programa se adicionar no model de usuário ou utilizando a dica do @bigown, ai vou poder optar pela solução menos prejudicial.